# Determine if cell exists in a specified range w/ Powershell Excel COM

Tags: excel, powershell, com, excel-formula

For example, I'm looking to determine the following logic:

```
if (B2 in A1:B20)  # if cell B2 is within the range A1:B20
{
   return $true
}
```

Is there a function within excel that can be used for something like this? I read about =COUNTIF() function but was not able to get it working. Again this is using an Excel COM object within Powershell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cell names are basically coordinates, this is purely a question of arithmetic comparison, no need to involve Excel itself:

```
function Test-CellInRange
{
    param(
        [ValidatePattern('^[A-Z]+\d+$')]
        [string]$Cell,
        [ValidatePattern('^[A-Z]+\d+\:[A-Z]+\d+$')]
        [string]$Range
    )

    # Grab X and Y coordinates from Range input, sort in ascending order (low to high)
    $P1,$P2 = $Range -split ':'
    $Xpoints = ($P1 -replace '\d'),($P2 -replace '\d') |Sort-Object
    $Ypoints = ($P1 -replace '\D'),($P2 -replace '\D') |Sort-Object

    # Grab X and Y coordinate from cell
    $CellX = $Cell -replace '\d'
    $CellY = $Cell -replace '\D'

    # Test whether cell coordinates are within range
    return ($CellX -ge $Xpoints[0] -and $CellX -le $Xpoints[1] -and $CellY -ge $Ypoints[0] -and $CellY -le $Ypoints[1])
}
```

Use it like:

```
if(Test-CellInRange -Cell B2 -Range A1:B20){
    "B2 is in A1:B20"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you show an example of how you'd call this function? I am having a bit of trouble understanding the regex pattern

Comment: @Quanda Added an example! The ValidatePattern attributes just make sure that the Cell coordinates are always the correct format (ie. `[one or more letters][one or more numbers]`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the COM interface (never used it), but if you have access to the [INTERSECT Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx) then you could write something like this:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2"), Range("A1:B20")) Is Nothing Then
    CODE_IF_TRUE
End If
```

It just does a set intersection of the two ranges. If they don't intersect, then the one is definitely not a subset of the other. If you need to check for a proper subset, you'd have to get more creative and check whether the intersection was the same as the entire desired subset. Remember your set logic and check out the [UNION Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) - between these things you should be able to handle any sort of operations you want.